# How to configure VSCode to run Java MAVEN applications with parameters?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, maven-2, maven-3

I have a code without main method. The project was executed using the following command:

```sh
$mvn clean install -Dparam1="folder" -Dparam2="path"
```

In Eclipse or IntelliJ, I just need to create a maven executor, define the goas as `clean install` and pass the maven parameters using the `-Dparam` format.

In VSCode, I have saw 3 different approaches and experimented the following:

1. Create a `lunch.json` file calling the command `mvn` or `mvnDebug` in the `preLaunchTask`.

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        ...
        "preLaunchTask": "mvnDebug",
        "vmArgs": [ "clean", "install", "-Dparam1=\"blabla\"", "-Dparam2=\"blablabla\"" ]

    }
  ]
}
```

I also have tested passing all the commands in the `preLaunchTask` without the `vmArgs`. And did not work.

2. Creating a `task.json` file passing the script and a `launch.json` file which will call in `preLaunchTask` the task created with the name defined in the parameter `taskName` of `task.json`.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "Debug",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
```

And the `tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Debug",
            "type": "java",
            "script": "mvnDebug clean install -Dparam1=\"folderName\" -Dparam2=\"blablabla\"",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

3. The 3rd approache I've tried was using `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "maven.terminal.favorites": [
        {
            "alias": "CLEAN COMPILE",
            "command": "clean install -Dparam1=\"value\" -Dparam2=\"blabla\"",
            "debug": true
        },
    ]
}
```

For all of them I got the message in the terminal:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 56787
```

What I need from you, guys, is:

1. What does this message means?
2. Why is it waiting for a port?
3. How does VSCode use a socket to do it?
4. What is the best approach and why?
5. **THE MOST IMPORTANT ONE**: How to run my JAVA MAVEN parameterized without a main function code using VSCode?

**OBSERVATION: My JAVA version is JDK11, but I've tried with JDK 8 too.**

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 5):

1.In `launch.json`, the attribute `vmArgs` is

> The extra options and system properties for the JVM (for example
> -Xms -Xmx -D=), it accepts a string or an array of string.
> [debugging-launch](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch)

so it won't work for your application.

2.In `tasks.json`, the attribute `command` is for the command to execute;

> [Custome Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)

3.It's recomended to use the setting `maven.executable.options`
, which specifies default options for all mvn commands.

> [vscode-maven](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven)

[image]

Comment: The answer was good, although the links without transcribing or copying some or the appropriate info, makes it annoying for lurking people